# Terraform dynamic block and list(object) error in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a root module, variable module and child module. I am receiving: **The given value is not suitable for child module variable "rule" defined at .. .. element 0: attribute "match" •
attribute "expr": element 0: attribute "expression " :
element 0: object required .
element 0:**

Root module:

```
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "policy" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name = var.waf_name
  #creating a dynamic rule
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.rule
    content {
      action = rule.value.action
      priority = rule.value.priority
      dynamic "match" {
        for_each = rule.value.match
        content {
          dynamic "expr" {
            for_each = match.value.expr
            content{
              dynamic "expression" {
                for_each = expr.value.expression
                content{
                  evaluatePreconfiguredExpr = expression.value.evaluatePreconfiguredExpr
                }
              }
            }
           }
        }  
      }
    }
  }
```

Variable Module(variable.tf):

```
 variable "rule" {
  description = "WAF rule 1"
  type        = list(object(
    {
      action = list(string)
      priority = list(string)
      match = list(object(
        {
          expr = list(object(
            {
              expression = list(object(
                {
                evaluatePreconfiguredExpr= list(string)
                }
              ))
            }
          ))
        }
      ))
    }
  )) 
}
```

Child module(main.tf or input module)

```
rule =[{
action   = ["deny(403)"]
priority = ["1000"]
match = [{
  expr = [{
    expression = [<<EOF
    evaluatePreconfiguredExpr('xss-stable', ['owasp-crs-v030001-id941340-xss',
      'owasp-crs-v030001-id941130-xss',
      'owasp-crs-v030001-id941170-xss',
      'owasp-crs-v030001-id941330-xss',
    ]
    )
    EOF
    ]
}]
```

}]
The reference site for this one is: https://github.com/DeimosCloud/terraform-google-waf/blob/master/main.tf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expanded `rule` parameter doesn't match the provider spec [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_security_policy) so it's being rejected.
For example, you're passing a list of objects for the `match` parameter but the spec requires a single object.
Tweaking the files as so works for me:

root.tf:

```
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "policy" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = var.waf_name
  #creating a dynamic rule
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.rule
    content {
      action   = rule.value.action
      priority = rule.value.priority
      dynamic "match" {
        for_each = rule.value.match
        content {
          dynamic "expr" {
            for_each = rule.value.match
            content {
              expression = expr.value.expression
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

variable.tf:

```
variable "rule" {
  description = "WAF rule 1"
  type = list(object(
    {
      action   = string
      priority = string
      match = object(
        {
          expr = object(
            {
              expression = string
            }
          )
        }
      )
    }
    )
  )
}
```

child.tf:

```
rule = [{
    action   = "deny(403)"
    priority = "1000"
    match = {
      expr = {
        expression = <<EOF
    evaluatePreconfiguredExpr('xss-stable', ['owasp-crs-v030001-id941340-xss',
      'owasp-crs-v030001-id941130-xss',
      'owasp-crs-v030001-id941170-xss',
      'owasp-crs-v030001-id941330-xss',
    ]
    )
    EOF
      }
    }
  }]
```

This produces the following plan:

```
  + resource "google_compute_security_policy" "policy" {
      + fingerprint = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "test"
      + project     = "something"
      + self_link   = (known after apply)

      + rule {
          + action   = "deny(403)"
          + preview  = (known after apply)
          + priority = 1000

          + match {

              + expr {
                  + expression = <<-EOT
                            evaluatePreconfiguredExpr('xss-stable', ['owasp-crs-v030001-id941340-xss',
                              'owasp-crs-v030001-id941130-xss',
                              'owasp-crs-v030001-id941170-xss',
                              'owasp-crs-v030001-id941330-xss',
                            ]
                            )
                    EOT
                }
            }
        }
    }
```